# In sails.js: fetch model's data from remote server

Tags: sails.js

my sails.js app is embedded in php project where php generate some date for sails model. Can't find the way to fetch this date in beforeCreate callback or some custom method. I don't want use db to sync 2 models (model from sails & model from php). And i need to send some date to remote php app.

sails.js v.0.9.x

here is my controller:

```
module.exports = {
    index: function (req, res) {},

    create: function (req, res) {
        if ( !req.param('login') )
          throw new Error('Login is undefined');
        if ( !req.param('message') )
          throw new Error('Initial message is undefined');
        var user, thread;
        User.create({
          id: 1,
          name: req.param('login'),
          ip: req.ip
        }).done( function (err, model) {
          user = model;
          if (err) {
            return res.redirect('/500', err);
          }
          user.fetch();  // my custom method
        });

        return res.view({ thread: thread });
      }
    };
```

and model:

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {

        id: 'integer',

        name: 'string',

        ip: 'string',

        fetch: function (url) {

            var app = sails.express.app;
            // suggest this but unlucky :)
            app.get('/path/to/other/loc', function (req, res, next) {
                console.log(req, res)

                return next()
            });
        }
    }

};
```

UPD My solution

Model:

```
beforeCreate: function (values, next) {

    var options = 'http://localhost:1337/test',
        get = require('http').get;

    get(options, function (res) {

        res.on('data', function (data) {

            _.extend( values, JSON.parse( data.toString() ) );
            next();

        });

    }).on('error', function () {

        throw new Error('Unable to fetch remote data');
        next();

    });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yikes--`app.get` is nowhere near what you need.  That's binding a route handler inside of your app and has nothing to do with requesting remote data.  Don't do this.

The easiest way to fetch remote data in Node is using the [**Request** library](https://github.com/mikeal/request).  First install it in your project directory using `npm install request`.  Then at the top of your model file:

```
var request = require('request');
```

and in your `fetch` method:

```
fetch: function(url, callback) {

    request.get(url, function(error, response, body) {
        return callback(error, body);
    });

}
```

Note the added `callback` parameter for `fetch`; this is needed because the request is an *asynchronous* operation.  That is, the call to `fetch()` will return immediately, but the request will take some time, and when it's done it will send the result back via the callback function.  Seeing as `fetch` is at this point just a wrapper around `request.get`, I'm not sure why it's necessary to have it as a model method at all, but if the URL was based on something within the model instance then it would make sense.

Comment: thanks for your respond. my way was similar with require('https').get